# How to import jasmine test functions in Angular2 rc5

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am working on a new project and just upgraded from rc4 to rc5 of Angular 2. Upon upgrading it appears that functions like it, expect, describe, etc are no longer being exported from '@angular/core/testing'. I have searched every resource I can think of and I see unit tests written online that claim to be using rc5 that still have these Jasmine test functions. Where do you import these from using rc5? Is there a new dependency library that I'm missing?

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
  "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
  "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
  "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
  "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
  "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
  "bootstrap": "twbs/bootstrap#v4-dev",
  "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
  "fullcalendar": "^2.7.3",
  "jquery": "^2.2.4",
  "jquery-datetimepicker": "^2.5.4",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
  "material-icons": "^0.1.0",
  "moment": "^2.13.0",
  "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.22",
  "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
  "primeui": "^4.1.12",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
  "systemjs": "0.19.26",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
  "clang-format": "^1.0.35",
  "codelyzer": "0.0.14",
  "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
  "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
  "karma": "^0.13.15",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
  "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
  "protractor": "^3.3.0",
  "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
  "tslint": "^3.6.0",
  "typescript": "^1.8.10",
  "typings": "^0.8.1"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They no longer need to be imported from anywhere as of RC4. They're made available globally to any testing module.

> Importing Jasmine functions from `@angular/core/testing` is no longer necessary and is now deprecated.

See also the last bullet point of the [Breaking Changes section of the RC4 Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1).

Comment: Welcome! Those changelogs can be a beast to parse through, and there's a lot that is overlooked. I usually have to read them several times over a few days.